# Question about linear transformation(mcq)

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $W$ be a vector space over $R$ and let $T:R^{6}\to W$ be a linear transformation,such that $S={[Te_2,Te_4,Te_6]}$ spans $W$.Which one of the following must be true?

$1.S$ is a basis of $W$.

$2.$$T(R^{6})\ne W$

$3.${${Te_1,Te_3,Te_5}$}spans $W$.

$4.$ker$(T)$ contains more than one element.

I am sure second option isn't correct if  $T(a,b,c,d,e,f)=a$ but can't think about others.

Comment: What could mcq possibly mean?

Comment: @copper.hat Multiple choice question.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: Thanks, I was thinking of a modifier for a linear transformation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is clear that 4. holds, by the [rank-nullity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem). All others are false.

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider each statement individually.

$1.$ Is $S$ a basis for $W$. We know from the hypothesis that $S$ span $W$, so the question is are $Te_2,$ $Te_4,$ $Te_6$ linearly independent. Suppose you have the map $T: \mathbb{R}^6 \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $T(e_{2i})=1$ and $T(e_{2i-1})=0$. This would be an example where $S$ spans $W$, but is not a linearly independent set.

$2.$ As you mentioned, this is also wrong. The reason is that since $S$ spans and $S \subset T(\mathbb{R}^6)$, then $T(\mathbb{R}^6)$ spans as well.

$3.$ We have no information to where these basis elements go. The example given in $1$ is also a counter example for that statement.

$4.$ This one is true. Indeed, if $W$ is spanned by $S$, then there must be more than one element in the kernel of $T$. For example, you can write $T(e_{1})$ in terms of elements in $S$. So there exist $s' \in \text{span}\{e_2,e_4,e_6\}$ such that $T(s')=T(e_1)$. This means that $T(e_1-s')=0$. Therefore $e_1-s' \in \ker(T).$ THe same is true for $e_3$ and $e_5$.